# Compare 20+ attributes in PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql

We have many-many items in database (postgresql) with 20+ attributes.
Example:

```
attr1 = 10.5
attr2 = 5
attr3 = 12.3
...
attr25 = 3
```

Question1. If we add new item with attributes, we need to find any items which have the same attributes values (all or 1-2 attributes can be not equal)?
Example:

```
db.attr1 = new.attr1
db.attr2 = new.attr2
...
db.attr25 = new.attr25
but db.attr7 can be not equals new.attr7 (or attr11, for example)
```

Question2. What is the best way to store this attributes in database, if we need decide question1?

**EDIT**

1. Attributes are constant, constant number of attributes = 24 and constant names
2. Performance - it's second question. Main problem - how I can to find items with not full equals attributes: 1 or 2 attributes can be not equal (not full duplicated)

Comment: You shouldn't be storing the attributes in different columns. You should create a one-to-many relationship between the "thing" and its attributes

Comment: Ok. But search will be more expensive if we create one-to-many.
And how we can search not full equals?
And attributes are constant, constant number - 24 and constant names.

Comment: Why do you think "search" (whatever you mean with that) would be "more expensive"? Did you test it? Do you have a specific performance problem when properly normalizing your model? And I have no idea what you mean with "can search not full equals"? What you are trying to implement is known as the (anti) pattern "entity attribute value". Search for that term. In Postgres you might be better of storing that in a `hstore` column.

Comment: Ok, performance - it's second question. EAV with constant attributes?
"can search not full equals" - I need to find all items with full equals attributes, but 1 or 2 attributes can be not equal.